# Different behaviour for these commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm having trouble understanding why there is a difference in the outputs of these 3 commands when executed on different distributions
Could you guys help me understand why ?

```sh
 printf "%s" `echo ../.. | sed 's/[.]/\\&/g'`
output on kali: &&/&&~    output on ubuntu: &&/&&

printf "%s" $(echo ../.. | sed 's/[.]/\\&/g')
output on kali: \.\./\.\.   output on ubuntu: ../..

printf "%s" "$(echo ../.. | sed 's/[.]/\\&/g')"
output on kali: \.\./\.\.     output on ubuntu: \.\./\.\.
```

Comment: `printf "%s" \`\`echo ../..` something wrong here, the \` are not in pairs. `output on kali` `output on ubuntu` What shell are you using on kali? what shell and verison are you using on ubuntu?

Comment: My research tells me that Kali uses zsh, ubuntu uses dash. What is the output of `echo $ZSH_VERSION` on both? What is the output of `echo $0` on both?

Comment: `output on ubuntu: ../..` that is very very odd, looks like a bug for me.

Answer (score 3):

Kali uses Zsh shell. Ubuntu uses Bash shell.

> ```
> output on ubuntu: &&/&&
> ```

Do not use backticks - prefer `$(...)`. Backticks remove `\` *before* execution.

```
printf "%s" `echo ../.. | sed 's/[.]/\\&/g'`
```

becomes:

```
printf "%s" $(echo ../.. | sed 's/[.]/\&/g')
```

So replaces `.` by `&` character.

> ```
> output on kali: &&/&&~
> ```

The `~` on the end in Zsh **in your configuration** represents output from a command without a newline.

> ```
> output on ...: \.\./\.\.
> ```

That should be understandable.

> ```
>  output on ubuntu: ../..
> ```

Aaaand this is the hard one around Bash 5.0. Unquoted result of command substitution undergo filename expansion (also called pathname expansion). The `\.\./\.\.` matches the directory path `../..`. Bash 5.0 introduced a change that would make the result of expansion undergo pathname expansion even if it doesn't have any globbing special characters.

The change was reversed in Bash 5.1. [Bash-5.1-alpha available for download](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-06/msg00064.html) https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-01/msg00063.html.